# What is the right way of doing Javascript static class inheritance with property override?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, static

I've found many posts on class inheritance but not about this specific problem with changing properties on static classes.

Here is the problem: I'm trying to implement class inheritance on JavaScript on a static class that will have some general static methods and will be extended by child classes, static as well. Child classes may add more static methods and will change a configuration object. None of them will be instantiated so I assume that I can't create the `body` property on the constructor as it will not be called. I have the following code working but I think it might not be the right way to do this.

Could you suggest a better alternative?

```js
class Animal{
    static get body(){
        return {
            legs: null,
            head: 1,
        }
    }
    static getLegs(){
        return this.body.legs;
    }
    static getHead(){
        return this.body.head;
    }
}
class Ant extends Animal{
    static get body(){
        return {
            legs: 6,
            head: 1,
        }
    }
}
class Monster extends Animal{
    static get body(){
        return {
            legs: 4,
            head: 2,
        }
    }
}
console.log(Animal.getLegs(), Animal.getHead());
console.log(Ant.getLegs(), Ant.getHead());
console.log(Monster.getLegs(), Monster.getHead());
```

Comment: The code is working, your child class functions are successfully shadowing the parent class functions. I'm not sure what you might be looking to improve here?

Comment: @CertainPerformance returning a new object every time I try to get the body doesn't look very performant. I wonder if there is a way of using variables or properties outside the construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the problem, but you can write something like this if you are using Babel.

```js
class Animal {
  static body = {
    legs: null,
    head: 1,
  };

  static getLegs() {
    return this.body.legs;
  }
  static getHead() {
    return this.body.head;
  }
}

class Ant extends Animal {
  static body = {
      legs: 6,
      head: 1
  };
}

class Monster extends Animal {
  static body = {
      legs: 4,
      head: 2,
  }
}
console.log(Animal.getLegs(), Animal.getHead());
console.log(Ant.getLegs(), Ant.getHead());
console.log(Monster.getLegs(), Monster.getHead());
```

Answer (score 2):

`class`es are there for creating objects inheriting a prototype in a more convenient way. Actually JS has prototypal inheritance (objects got prototypes) so we could just use that:

```
 const animal = {
   body: { // you can fall back to a getter at any time
      legs: null,
      head: 1,
  },
  get legs(){
    return this.body.legs;
  },
  get head(){
    return this.body.head;
  }
};

const ant = Object.assign(Object.create(animal), {
  body: {
     legs: 6,
     head: 1,
  },
});
```

If you need the class for something else you can still set a property:

```
 class Animal{
    static get legs(){
       return this.body.legs;
    }
    static get head(){
        return this.body.head;
    }
 }

Animal.body = { legs: null, head: 1, };
```

Comment: Is it possible to write that in class syntax?

Comment: @vandervals yes, it is

Comment: That is good, thanks! I couldn't figure out a way to put that body prop INSIDE the class declaration, hehe. This shall work of course.

Comment: @vandervals that will be possible in the future, static class properties are proposed already.

Comment: @JonasW. can you really set properties like that with `Object.create()`?  I though you would need `body:  value:{legs:6, head:1}` Similar to property descriptors

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a new object each time `body` is getted, you might put each class's object into a variable and return that variable. Or, you might make the code cleaner with a `Map` that returns the object indexed at `this`, allowing for only one `get body` definition:

```js
const { Animal, Ant, Monster } = (() => {
  class Animal {
    static get body() {
      return bodies.get(this)
    }
    static getLegs() {
      return this.body.legs;
    }
    static getHead() {
      return this.body.head;
    }
  }
  class Ant extends Animal {}
  class Monster extends Animal {}
  const bodies = new Map([
    [Animal, {
      legs: null,
      head: 1
    }],
    [Ant, {
      legs: 6,
      head: 1
    }],
    [Monster, {
      legs: 4,
      head: 2
    }]
  ]);
  return { Animal, Ant, Monster };
})();
console.log(Animal.getLegs(), Animal.getHead());
console.log(Ant.getLegs(), Ant.getHead());
console.log(Monster.getLegs(), Monster.getHead());
```

The IIFE ensures that the bodies are semi-private (though, they'll still be mutable if the object itself gets returned). If you want to additionally prevent the objects from being mutated when they're returned, you can use `Object.freeze`. (That doesn't *guarantee* that the objects won't be mutable - they can be unfrozen if done explicitly - but it'll make it a lot more difficult for accidental mutations to happen)

Comment: Well, compared to having `get body` for each `class`